# Cannot read package Name from Android Manifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I'm a beginner in developing Android Studio projects. I have tried all the solutions from other questions and it does not solve my issue. When I build the apk I get this error:

> Error:Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\konstantinos\AndroidStudioProjects\WIFIConnectionListener-master\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

This is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.wificonnectionlistener">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <receiver
        android:name=".WifiBroadCastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".TextToSpeechService" >
    </service>
</application>
</manifest>
```

This is my built.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.wificonnectionlistener"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 15
         versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your app.gradle file including buildscript { .... etc } which is not included in app level gradle file it should be on parent level gradle please verify it.

Comment: Your app gradle should be like this.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.wificonnectionlistener"
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 15
   versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    }
}

Comment: There are no activities in your manifest.